# Does Play Billing Library support UPI with IAP?

Tags: in-app-purchase, billing, upi

Can I support UPI with the IAP payment method of Google play? At present, Indian users display UPI entries when they purchase, but they cannot buy them normally. What do you need to do?

Comment: https://www.androidauthority.com/google-play-store-upi-india-1027085/ I guess. Otherwise, _"they cannot buy them normally"_ is not a problem description, so you need to provide more detail on what you have tried and how that failed.

Comment: I am a developer, my app is online, and supports billing, but Indian users can bind his UPI when buying, but will be prompted to purchase this item failed. The same problem exists with other in-app subscriptions, but it is ok to buy directly at the Google Store.

Comment: _"will be prompted to purchase this item failed"_ Could you include a quote or screenshot of the precise error(s) received?